# Android ignores the autoOrients setting in XML after reloading app

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.6

I have a small problem with my Android app.
Within my control XML i have

```
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
```

and this works also on the first start of the application. The app starts in landscape mode and everything works perfectly.
Then, i click the home button (or the phone goes to standbye mode). Now i select the application from the tasklist or click the application icon. The application is now in portrait mode (for which he is not designed for) and since i have disabled the autoOrients, i cannot switch back to landscape mode.

Is this a bug in Flex 4.6 (i work with Adobe Flash Builder 4.6) or is there some other switch missing?

Best regards KjM

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar issues; I believe with some versions of Android.  I added code like this to my main application file.  It uses the applicationComplete and the activate events to set the aspect ratio of the app at runtime.  It is a backup for when the descriptor setting gets wonky.

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                            firstView="something"   
applicationComplete="viewnavigatorapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)"
activate="viewnavigatorapplication1_activateHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            protected function viewnavigatorapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.stage.setAspectRatio( StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE );
            }

            protected function viewnavigatorapplication1_activateHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                if(this.stage){
                    this.stage.setAspectRatio( StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE );
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Comment: I had near the same solution (NativeApplication, Eventlistener for the ACTIVATE event) but for unkown reason the result was an endless loop calling the setAspectRatio() function :|

Comment: I'm not sure, then.  I don't have an S3 to test personally.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<activity
            android:name="xxxx"
            android:label="xxxxx"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
```

to your activity tag in the manifest

Comment: He is using Flex/AIR.  I'm pretty sure that the Android Manifest is created behind the scenes by the AIR Compiler; based on his Flex/AIR Application Descriptor file.  I'd guess that the aspectRatio element he specifies will translate into screenOrientation; but I don't actually know that.  I think he could add this in the manifestAdditions section of his app descriptor; but he shouldn't have to.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. The compiler throws and error about unbound element :(

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following values in your main-app.xml

```
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
```

Your Mobile App will start now with the portrait aspect ratio, regardless the orientation of the mobile device. Your app will ignore now the rotation of your mobile device.